# Medir tiempo de ejecución de un algoritmo en Android

Tags: java, android

Necesito medir el tiempo en el que se ejecuta un algoritmo en Android. Por ejemplo: quiero comparar la velocidad en que se obtiene el Factorial de un número hecho por recursividad y hecho sin este.

Este es mi programa:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnCalcular;
    EditText input;
    TextView txtResultado, txtTiempo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputNumero);
        btnCalcular = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalcular);
        txtResultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResultado);
        txtTiempo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTiempo);

        btnCalcular.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
        int fact = factorial(number);
        txtResultado.setText("El factorial de " +number+ " es: " +fact);
    }

    public static int factorial(int number) {
        if (number <= 1)
            return 1;
        return number * factorial(number - 1);
    }
}
```

Espero sus respuestas.

Comment: Cabe aclarar que el usuario no esta requiriendo del uso de "micro benchmarking", por lo tanto agrego mi respuesta, Saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para medir el tiempo transcurrido si es que no requieres de "micro benchmarking", definir al iniciar tu proceso:

```
long tInicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

al finalizar tu proceso:

```
long tFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();
long tDiferencia = tFinal - tInicio;
```

Puedes convertir la diferencia a segundos:

```
double segundosTranscurridos = tDiferencia/1000.0;
```

Por lo tanto en tu código sería:

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        long tInicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
        int fact = factorial(number);
        txtResultado.setText("El factorial de " +number+ " es: " +fact);
        long tFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long tDiferencia = tFinal - tInicio;
        //double segundosTranscurridos = tDiferencia/1000.0;
        txtTiempo.setText("tiempo transcurrido : "  + String.valueOf(tDiferencia) +  " millisegundos.");
    }
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Que raro que este mal, esto es lo que se realiza en aplicaciones Android, para medir el tiempo de procesos!.

Comment: Se puede realizar profiling para obtener datos "super" exact pero creo que el OP no creo requiera de realizar benchmark a ese nivel, únicamente medir el tiempo transcurrido.

Comment: "Profiling with Traceview", Vamos a ver que dice el usuario que es el más importante. =)

Comment: Yo te recomendaría otros titulos!

Comment: Es una lástima que no sepas reconocer que hay algo nuevo que puedas aprender y lo que indicas no es correcto, inclusive cuando la información es precisa y directa y está delante tuyo. En fin...

Comment: Gracias por la información a ambos. Estoy aprendiendo poco a poco pero por ahora lo que necesitaba era algo básico como lo que propuso @Elenasys... Solo que en vez de usar System.currentTimeMillis() use System.nanoTime() para que se note más la diferencia de variación.

Estoy comparando tiempos de distintos algoritmos recursivos tanto en Java (Android) como en Swift (iOS)... Si alguien tiene idea como hacerlo en Swift estaría agradecido!

Comment: @JuanSánchez en swift esta manera es válida, inclusive hay utilitarios que realizan esa medición por ti. En Java esto no funciona debido a la complejidad de la JVM puesto que al ejecutar un bloque de código X una cierta cantidad de veces se lanza el JIT que va a optimizar el bytecode y hasta puede que algunas operaciones de bucle O(N) pasen a tiempo constante (!) O(1), por lo que el uso de `System.currentTimeMills` o `System.nanoTime` simplemente no aplica.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que pides se llama Micro Benchmark. Existen librerías en Java para ejecutar micro benchmarks y comparar los resultados de tiempo de ejecución de códigos.

---

Nota antes de continuar: Si alguien te dice inocentemente *utiliza `System#currentTimeMillis` antes y después de tu código*, esta persona **no conoce absolutamente nada de cómo funciona la JVM**. En otros lenguajes fuera de la JVM esa técnica puede funcionar, pero no con la JVM. Sucede que la JVM hace varias optimizaciones cuando se ejecutan ciertos fragmentos de código luego de varias iteraciones, por lo cual si sigues esa "recomendación" tendrías algo como esto (es una idea):

```
medirTiempo(metodo1); 5.4s
medirTiempo(metodo2); 2.1s
```

Y al invertir la ejecución

```
medirTiempo(metodo2); 5.7s
medirTiempo(metodo1); 1.8s
```

Y no sabrías si los resultados son adecuados.

> Pero ponlo en un loop

Peor aún. La JVM ejecuta optimizaciones cuando el código se ejecuta varias veces, mucho más cuando se tienen los mismos resultados. Es decir, este código:

```
for
    medirTiempo(metodo1)
end for 20.1s
for
    medirTiempo(metodo2)
end for 8.1s
```

Al invertir su ejecución

```
for
    medirTiempo(metodo2)
end for 30.4s
for
    medirTiempo(metodo1)
end for 13.6s
```

Entonces, sigue la gran duda: **¿cuál implementación tiene mejor rendimiento?**

---

Para Java, puedes escribir micro benchmarks utilizando [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) y [Caliper](https://github.com/google/caliper). Puesto que tu micro benchmark está orientado a probar aplicaciones Android, te recomiendo que utilices Caliper porque está construido por el equipo de Google y es el framework que ellos utilizan para escribir sus benchmarks, tal como indican en [la documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Measure):

> ## Always Measure
>
> Before you start optimizing, make sure you have a problem that you need to solve. Make sure you can accurately measure your existing performance, or you won't be able to measure the benefit of the alternatives you try.
>
> Every claim made in this document is backed up by a benchmark. The source to these benchmarks can be found in the code.google.com "dalvik" project.
>
> The benchmarks are built with the Caliper microbenchmarking framework for Java. Microbenchmarks are hard to get right, so Caliper goes out of its way to do the hard work for you, and even detect some cases where you're not measuring what you think you're measuring (because, say, the VM has managed to optimize all your code away). We highly recommend you use Caliper to run your own microbenchmarks.

Traducido (énfasis mía):

> ## Siempre Medir
>
> Antes que empieces las optimizaciones, asegúrate de tener un problema que necesitas resolver. Asegúrate que mides tu rendimiento existente de manera precisa, o no estarás habilitado para medir el beneficio de las alternativas que pruebas.
>
> Cada elemento hecho en este documento está respaldado por un benchmark. Las fuentes de estos benchmarks pueden ser encontrados en el proyecto "dalvik" en code.google.com.
>
> Los benchmarks están escritos con el marco de trabajo para microbenchmarks Caliper. Los microbenchmarks son difíciles de realizar de manera correcta, así que Caliper te ayuda a hacer el trabajo duro, e inclusive detectar algunos casos donde no estás midiendo lo que crees que estás midiendo (porque, digamos, la máquina virtuale ha conseguido optimizar tódo el código posible). **Nosotros [Google] recomendamos altamente usar Caliper para ejecutar tus propios microbenchmarks**.

---

> ¿Y no puedo utilizar JMH para escribir microbenchmarks en Java?

Claro que puedes. Pero JMH es un proyecto de OpenJDK y está más orientado a OpenJDK y HotSpot, proyectos mantenidos por la comunidad Java y Oracle respectivamente. Los dispositivos Android utilizan Dalvik, la implementación de la JVM de Google, por ende los resultados que arrojen JMH puede que no sean los más adecuados para Dalvik.

Answer (score 0):

El código que te publicare a continuación esta desarrollado en java esto se puede adaptar ya que android trabaja con java puro posee un ejemplo a continuación anexo código único de calculo de tiempo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy buena aportación, pero te recomiendo agregar el código y no imagenes, saludos! =)